# How to do new line in comments

Tags: support, comment, formatting

Take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649371/find-greatest-value-of-yx-0-9x300x-650/649374#649374) and you'll notice that in the comments on that answer, he provided mathematical expressions on a new line. Is that just because there was not enough space left on the line, so it skipped to a new line, or did he purposely do that? If so, how?

Comment: Put two dollar signs on each side of an expression to force it to stand in the center of its own line.

Comment: @T.Bongers That's all I wanted. You can write that up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Older question here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309/allow-newline-in-comments and on meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments

Comment: If you want to make a newline in comments, but you do not want math mode you might do the following: \$\$\mbox{  }\$\$. This will give the following $$\mbox{ }$$ as a space.

Comment: @BabyDragon or you can just do four dollar signs. Do you know how to do it on Stack Overflow?